# How to organize and structure an Expressjs application with Zurb's Foundation?

Tags: express, zurb-foundation

I'm using an node's express framework in the back-end and foundation on the front-end, for a website. However I'm having difficulty organizing the project (nested Git repositories). I have a simple project layout (default):

```
project
  app.js
  node_modules
  routes
  views
  public
    css
      app.css
    ..
  package.json
  foo  // a foundation project generated using "foundation new foo --libsass"
```

I need to have the **foo** folder inside my express project to manage my sass files & to update foundation.

The problem is that foo is a clone of a git repository (kinda boilerplate). Now to make my main express project into a git repository, I think I've to use Git modules.

Can anybody recommend a better way?